# Why artificial zero array can increase the accuracy of time series data prediction

Tags: python, time-series, prediction, categorical-data

The following data frame (picture 1) is an example of my data. It's a binary category time series data.

I use Adaboost to train and predict my data, and the scoring system is F1 score.

**I found out that the accuracy of the prediction will increase a lot if I artificially create 1-year data with all rows of the dependent variable (Alpha wave appear?) equal to 0 (picture 2) and add it back to the original data set. (nothing else change in the model)**

The true positive increases a little bit and the false negative decreases a lot.

Is this just coincident? Or there is any theory behind it?

I tried to predict different years of data and this solution seems to work for most of the years.
And so I was just wondering whether it is possible that the zero data frame decreases the noise of time series data?

I don't have a solid background in data science. If someone can provide me any resources to explain this situation, that would be very helpful! (Or...just let me know this is just coincidence...)

Thank you.

picture 1.
[image]
picture 2.
[image]

Comment: how do you measure prediction accuracy?

Comment: basically I calculate true positive (TP), false negative (FN), false positive (FP) for each individual ID. And then I sum up and get the total TP, FN, FP so that I can calculate the total precision and recall and thus F1 score. The grid search and final model valuation are all based on total F1 score.

Comment: what data do you use to make those predictions?

Comment: what do you mean? The data is like what I posted. But training set is 2008 - 2018 and the test set is 2019 data

Comment: This is exactly what I meant, what is the validation data. Are training and testing sets follow the same distribution?